# Wildcard issue with Move-Item

Tags: powershell, wildcard

I'm trying to move all folders and their contents to a folder based upon the first part of the folder name.  For example, all folders that begin  with 2018 to a folder named 2018.  The folders all of the naming structure year-month-day ( xxxx-xx-xx ) so 2018-01-01, 2018-01-02, etc...  So, I tried to use Move-Item with a wildcards * and ? after year.

```
Move-Item . -Include 2018* .\2018
```

and

```
Move-Item . -Include 2018?????? .\2018
```

But I get this error:

> ```
> Move-Item : Cannot move item because the item at 'F:\My Share\One\More\Folder' does not exist.
> At line:1 char:1
> + Move-Item . -Include 2018* .\2018
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Move-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
> ```

I get the same error with either one.   I hope I included enough info to allow you to enlighten this greenhorn.  :-)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If the folder doesnt exist then you need to create it

Answer (score 1):

S.TECHS,

if the dir doesn't exist, Move-Item won't make it. well, it won't on win7ps5.1 - it may on win10 since there are several improvements there.

the following code works on win7ps5.1 by checking for the destination dir and making it if it aint there. [*grin*]

```
$SourceDir = $env:TEMP
$Filter = '20??-*'

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -Filter $Filter

foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)
    {
    $Year = $FL_Item.BaseName.Split('-')[0]
    $DestDir = Join-Path -Path $SourceDir -ChildPath $Year
    $FullDestFileName = Join-Path -Path $DestDir -ChildPath $FL_Item.Name

    if (-not (Test-Path $DestDir))
        {
        # suppress unwanted output of New-Item
        $Null = New-Item -Path $DestDir -ItemType Directory
        }

    Move-Item -LiteralPath $FL_Item.FullName -Destination $FullDestFileName
    }
```

hope that helps,
lee